# Powerpoint: Make object disappear on click on THIS VERY object

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like to **reveal answers** by clicking on the respective region of a slide, by the order clicked.

I know how to animate slides to introduce ("entrance") objects (or remove, "exit" covering boxes) in the **pre**defined order, and no matter where you click in the slide.

The point here is that I'd like to reveal (make appaer, or possibly easier make disappear a covering box) the answers **in the unpredictable order in the interactive presentation, i.e. I cannot pre-define the order** in "animation settings". Searching for answers just shows tons of answers explaining how to animate presentatins in a pre-defined order.

I tried action buttons and know how to hyperlink (also to another slide, but this does not help since there are too many combinations). "Object action" seemed promising, but is grayed out (and seems to apply only for OLE objects). Last, I tried "Run macro". [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707480/3414968) comes close, but I do not know how to apply the macro `ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("textbox 114").Visible = False` to the object just clicked.

Grateful for help within plain Powerpoint, if necessary also with macros. Working with Office 365 (if possible, luxury answer would cover also ancient versions so that I can present at work, but not strictly necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "on click" Trigger so often that I missed the option to select *what* to click on: on click of... Quite simple, but I have not seen anybody use this in a slideshow.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's not all that common, probably because triggers are often the solution to trickier problems than most people pose for themselves. They're quite useful.  You could also create a macro like Sub HideMe (oSh as Shape):osh.Visible=False:End Sub and apply it as an Action Setting | Run Macro | HideMe to each shape you want to be able to click to hide.

Comment: Macro seems more complicated (need xlsm file, that may irritate other people and firewalls) than using triggers, but you showed me how easy it is to apply the macro to the clicked object, +1 since helpful!

Comment: >> need xlsm file <<  Well, PPTM/PPSM rather than XLSM, but it's true that security settings might prevent macros from running.